# Как организовать изображения?

Tags: android, изображения, recyclerview, структуры-данных, android-spinner

подскажите как решить такую задачу.
Есть изображения (около 100 штук) уже в ужатом формате webp.

Эти изображения делятся по категориям, (к примеру пейзажи/еда/спорт ... итд) и в каждой категории есть своя подкатегория (еда - русская кухня/китайская итд, спорт - бокс/бег/футбол итд) и таких подкатегорий несколько ->  И нужно сделать так чтобы в выпадающем спиннере или в recyclerView при нажатии на категорию открывался спиннер/список с "внутренней" подкатегорией, потом следующая подкатегория и в этой подкатегории еще следующая итд, и при нажатии на конечную отображалась конкретное изображение.

Но самое сложное в этом, что я никак не могу понять это как организовать логику соответствия списка к изображениям, чтобы код не был громоздким. Потому как я только додумался до того чтобы создать map, сохранить отдельно все  виды категорий в stringах или массивах/arraylist, и просто в мапе перебрать каждый вариант конечного составленного stringа на соответствие ("food.asian.sushi" to "assets/sushi.webp", "sport.box" to "assets/boxer.webp") но до чего-то более умного не додумался.

Подскажите идею каким образом можно удобнее и быстрее прописать к каждому конечному itemу с той или иной категории соответствующее ему изображение?

Кстати правильно ли я сделал что изображения в формате webp поместил в заранее созданную папку assets? Изображения там и так небольшие (до 50кб), и мне не очень хочется делать их для каждого размера экрана чтобы много не занимало памяти конечное приложение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В папке `assets` можно создавать подпапки, таким образом перенести все дерево, а выбор содержимого текущего каталога осуществлять так

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
String[] list_assets = am.list(current_folder);
```

Очевидно, что при добавлении новых изображений не нужно пересоздавать дополнительные данные.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно было) Единственное что придется тогда переименовывать вручную все изображения чтобы они в recyclerе/спиннере соответствовали своему описанию.

Answer (score 1):

В случае что подкатегории не повторяются в других категориях и изображения тоже, простая древовидная структура подойдет.
Конкретнее JSON типа такого

```
[
  { 
    name: cat1,
    subcats: [
      {
         name: sub1,
         images: [ name1, name2, name3]
      },
      {
         name: sub2,
         images: [ ... ]
      },
    ]
  },
  { 
    name: cat2,
    subcats: [...]
  }
]
```

Вложенность можете организовать любую.
JSON как текст хранить в ресурсах или скачивать с сервера.

Comment: Хорошая идея, спасибо, как-то про JSON совсем забыл)